# Not Able To Install Windows 8 in my PC

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I was Having Only One partition in my Laptop (With Windows 8 64 bit,6gb hard disk,500 gb hard disk ,Intel Core i5 3427U @ 1.80GHz  Ivy Bridge 22nm Technology).
I decided to partition the Disk.I deleted All the System Reserved,and other factory partition,I also deleted 'c drive' When I choosed a partition to install windows 8 pro 64 bit It was giving me an Error of " windows can not be installed GsPT partition style".
Please Help me .
How Should i Partition my hard disk and Reinstall Windows 8??

Comment: I have Recovered it.But It is again a single partition???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are having a hard time there. This is how to solve it:

> To change a GUID partition table disk into a master boot record disk
>   using command line:
>
> **1** Back up or move all volumes on the basic GUID partition table (GPT) disk you want to convert into a master boot record (MBR) disk.
>
> **2** Open a command prompt and type diskpart. If the disk does not contain any partitions or volumes, skip to step 6.
>
> **3** At the DISKPART prompt, type list volume. Make note of the volume number you want to delete.
>
> **4** At the DISKPART prompt, type select volume .
>
> **5** At the DISKPART prompt, type delete volume.
>
> **6** At the DISKPART prompt, type list disk. Make note of the disk number of the disk that you want to convert to a GPT disk.
>
> **7** At the DISKPART prompt, type select disk .
>
> **8** At the DISKPART prompt, type convert mbr.

[source](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/cc725797.aspx)

To reach the command line during setup, press **shift+f10** or do as the pictures describe from start-up options:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Credits to on how to reach command prompt and image credits](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2755-command-prompt-boot-startup-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: Will this Conversion Will alter the performance or other issues??

Comment: it changes the partition type from GPT to MBR.BIOS installs of windows 8 64 bit work on an MBR basis, still, if you want an EFI install you will need a GPT partition.

Comment: Does the number of partiotion will create any problem,because i have 6 partition by default and all are user for system and other usage .I can access only C Drive

Comment: not in MBR, GPT does have limitations to primary partitions and the disk partitioning.